# Accessing App Config file creates an error

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I have to access app config file name as `App.config`

```
    MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSettings =App.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;

 if (mailSettings != null)
            {
                 FromMail = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.UserName;
                 password = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Password;
            }
```

App config file as

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="abc@email.com">
        <network host="smtp.server.com" port="587" userName="abc@email.com" password="password" enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

when i am accessing this way. It is showing that App doesn't exist in following context.Please Help.

Comment: That was i am missing the declaration but i have searched on net to. How to declare the it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to project properties->settings add your properties (such as user name and password).

if you want to properties can change from config file, set scope of property to 'Application'.

in code use like this:

```
FromMail = Properties.Settings.Default.UserName;
password = Properties.Settings.Default.Password;
```

you can change property value in GUI by:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = FromMail;
Properties.Settings.Default.Password = password;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

you can only change property which has USER scope.

Comment: Sir is it possible to change these setting value from Gui or is it possible to change it if i make one more form Name setting??

Comment: yes, you can update each property and save settings.
`Properties.Settings.Default.UserName="value";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`
you can load settings again with `Properties.Settings.Default.load()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Properties.Settings class to access the app.config file, check [Application Settings for Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e.aspx)